# How can I correctly create a centralized Git repository on a Linux Server? Why I have this error following this tutorial?

Tags: linux, git, version-control, git-bash

I am pretty new in Git and I am installing a centralized GIT repository on a Linux server following this tutorial: http://toroid.org/git-central-repo-howto

It show these 2 first steps:

```
$ git init --bare --shared foo.git
Initialized empty shared Git repository in /git/foo.git/
$ chgrp -R dev foo.git
```

So basically the first command:

```
git init --bare --shared foo.git
```

I think that it means that I am creating a new empty **foo** repository (is **foo** the name of the created repository?).

From what I have understand the **--bare** option means that this repository is not associated to a working tree. Why?

Reading this documentation: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-init I can understand that  **--shared** means that **this repository is to be shared amongst several users. This allows users belonging to the same group to push into that repository**.

But what users? Users of what?

The second statement is:

```
chgrp -R dev foo.git
```

From what I have understand it set the **foo.git** directory (my repository) and all its content to the **dev** group.

The problem is performing this command I obtain this error message in my shell:

```
XXX@YYY:~$ chgrp -R dev foo.git
chgrp: invalid group: ‘dev’
```

I am not so into Linux but I think that it means that the **dev** group doesn't exit on my server. Why have I to associate this repository folder (and its content) to a group? How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Re-read manual:

> The easy way to give people read-write access to it (repository) is to
>   add all the relevant users to one group (say dev), and give that group
>   ownership of the repository

and

> The --shared option sets the permissions on everything in the
>   repository to group-writable.

ssh:// access-type to repo assumed. I.e. user belongs to local group, all members of which have RW rigths in the repository on FS-level

Answer (score 0):

I'm quite new to GIT myself, but I think you just need to create linux group "dev" beforehand, or use an already existing group. You can add users of the linux server into that group. The users of the group could later clone/pull from/push to your repository.
Link about managing groups:

```
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/users_and_groups
```